# How to avoid decorating the first row of recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can I go about not decorating the first row in my recyclerview so that my Item decorator decorates every other row?

Answer (score 2):

Just check the child position in

```
@Override
public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
     }
   }
```

in your RecyclerView.ItemDecoration class.

Also a nice solution (to learn something more) can be found at https://github.com/yqritc/RecyclerView-FlexibleDivider

Answer (score 1):

In your onBindView() method, test the position var for 0.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with korrekorre's answer.

My code looks like:

```
    @Override public void getItemOffsets(
        Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    int l, t, r, b;
    l = leftMargin;
    t = topMargin;
    r = rightMargin;
    b = bottomMargin;
    if (mIgnoreAfterLast && parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == parent.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1) {
        if (mHorizontal) {
            r = 0;
        } else {
            b = 0;
        }
    }
    if (mIgnoreBeforeFirst && parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0) {
        if (mHorizontal) {
            l = 0;
        } else {
            t = 0;
        }
    }
    outRect.set(l, t, r, b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check for first position and 'return' in your custom RecyclerView.ItemDecoration. To be more exact, something like this:

```
@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
    int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);

    if (position == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION || position == 0) {
        return;
    }

    ...The rest of your decorator logic goes here...
}
```